# Что такое литерал обьекта?

Tags: javascript

Где здесь литерал объекта?
Или литерал - это свойства объекта?
Я запутался, помогите((

```
let user = {
  name: 'Колян',
  age: 32,
  weight: 87,
};
```

Comment: Ну в общем то все, что идет после оператора присваивания. Без точки с запятой)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В js есть разные способы создать объект. Одним из них является литерал, т.е. способ создания объекта, при котором вы указываете его свойства и методы в фигурных скобках. Способ создания объекта с помощью литерала появился в js начиная с ES3, и до него объекты можно было создать только с помощью конструктора

```js
// Способ создания объекта с помощью литерала
// лирералом является все что в {} включительно
let user = {
  name: 'Колян',
  age: 32,
  weight: 87,
}

// Способ создания об'екта с использованием констуктора Object
let user1 = new Object();
user1.name = 'Колян';
user1.age = 32;
user1.weight = 87;

// Еще один способ создания объекта с помощью конструктора
function User(name, age, weight){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.weight = weight
}
let user2 = new User('Колян', 32, 87);

console.log(user, user1, user2);


// Для ещё большей понятности: другой пример из мира js
  
// Создание массива с помощью литерала массивов
let array = [];

// Создание массива с помощью конструктора
let array1 = new Array();
```

Сейчас же эти подходы к созданию объекта отличаются только синтаксисом, но литеральная форма предпочтительнее, в виду того, что более читаемая.

Есть еще способы создать объект, но они уже отличаются не только синтаксически:

1. Использование метода Object.create(), который не только создаст объект, а еще установит переданный ей аргумент в качестве прототипа созданного, подробнее на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

```js
const userPrototype = {
  name: 'guest'
};

let user = Object.create(userPrototype);
let userOwnProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(user);

console.log('Объект: ', user);
console.log('Собственные поля объекта: ', userOwnProperties);

user.name = 'Колян';
userOwnProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(user);
console.log('Собственные поля объекта: ', userOwnProperties);
```

2. Использование js-классов (начиная с ES6) для которых доступно ключевое слово super, подробнее на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). В общем-то классы предпочтительнее, когда речь заходит о сложных объектах с множеством свойств и методов.

```js
class User {
  constructor(name, age, weight){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.weight = weight;
  };
  
  log(){
    console.log('Имя: ', this.name);
    console.log('Возвраст: ', this.age);
  }
  // Здесь еще методы пользователя
}

class Customer extends User {
  constructor(name, age, weight, preferences = []){
    super(name, age, weight);
    this.preferences = preferences
  }
  log(){
    super.log();
    console.log('Предпочтения', this.preferences);
  }
  // Здесь еще методы покупателя
}

let customer = new Customer('Колян', 32, 89);
customer.log();
```

Comment: А, про Object.create() забыли :)

Comment: Для полноты картины надо добавить новый способ, через `class`

Comment: Добавил информацию об обоих способах

Answer (score 0):

Вот эта часть - литерал

```
{
  name: 'Колян',
  age: 32,
  weight: 87,
}
```