# Почему одни экземпляры создаём через new, а другие литерально?

Tags: javascript

Всем добрый день.

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему экземпляры встроенных объектов, например, `Number`, `String`, `Boolean`, `Object`, `Function` мы создаем литерально, то есть объявляем переменную и присваиваем ей значение. А некоторые экземпляры объектов, которые тоже являются встроенными, мы создаём уже с помощью оператора `new`, например `Promise` или `Date`? Ведь те значения, строки, числа, булевые значения, объекты объявленные литерально, функции (которые мы объявляем как function declaration, не присваивая какой-либо переменной) - они ведь тоже являются экземплярами встроенных объектов, как и:

```
const promise = new Promise(/*some function as parameter*/);
const date = new Date();
```

Только `promise` и `date` мы почему-то создаем через оператор new, а те же числа, строки, объекты, булевые значения, function declaration/expression без оператора `new`. Объясните пожалуйста, почему именно так? Если любые значения являются по сути экземплярами определенных встроенных объектов.

Если я сделаю вот так:

```
console.log(new Number(1) + new Number(2)); // выводится 3 и typeof полученного значения number
То есть всё в порядке, это то же самое, как если бы мы сделали:

console.log(1 + 2);
```

И ничего не изменилось бы, но всё же не пойму, что почему некоторые экземпляры мы создаем исключительно через оператор `new` ? А не литерально.

*Важное замечание: Я сейчас не привязываюсь конкретно к встроенным объектам `Promise` и `Date`, экземпляры которых создаются через `new`, я их привёл исключительно в качестве примера, есть и куча других встроенных объектов, экземпляры которых мы создаем с помощью `new`. Поэтому не привязывайтесь пожалуйста в данном вопросе конкретно к `Promise` и `Date`!*

Comment: "а те же числа, строки, объекты, булевые значения, function declaration/expression без оператора new."  --- так кто же мешает. можете спокойно делать `new Boolean (false)` например и работать с объектом типа булеан........или создавать `Object` через `new Object`

Comment: ну и надо понимать, что есть объекты, а есть примитивы. можно с bool работать как с объектом , тогда работаем через `new`, а можем как с примитивом, тогда работаем просто с `true/false`....

Comment: [Простые типы данных и их обёртки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Primitive#%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%91%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B2_javascript)

Comment: в данном случае про промис и про дату можно сказать что их нельзя одназначно описать каким-то литералом, например '10/01/2022' - это дата или строка? по большей части отсутствие `new`  - это синтаксический сахар, под капотом это все есть.

Comment: @DaniilLoban, есть ли какие-то доказательства про _под капотом это все есть_?

Comment: В качестве доказательств по хорошему нужно было бы использовать исходники v8 обычно я так делаю, но у меня нет на это времени в данный момент, хотя я с удовольстивем гляну доказательство обратного. Что касается доказательства вообще то думаю спецификация языка - авторитетный источник. [ECMA-262.12th.edition.June.2021.pdf](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/releases/download/es2021/ECMA-262.12th.edition.June.2021.pdf)  внизу 306 страницы по документу или 310 по pdf есть объяснение, не та же версия редакции но [на русском](https://javascript.ru/ecma/part11#a-11.1.4)

Comment: @DaniilLoban, в указанном месте речь только про литерал массива, а в вопросе речь про литералы в общем (строки, числа).  Кроме того, в Note секции нет ничего про то, что `new` это синтаксический сахар. Там указывается только то, что элементы не обязаны быть литералами.

Comment: я писал `по большей части отсутствие new - это синтаксический сахар` и извините нет времени на споры

Comment: @DaniilLoban, и даже "по большей части" - тоже не совсем корректно

Comment: @DaniilLoban А откуда инфа, что отсутствие new - это синт. сахар?

Comment: @MarshallMathers например [отсюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: MarshallMathers так же думаю будет полезно почитать ответ [Anynomius](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1124053/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0)  + Grundy ♦ тогда у него вопросов не было к `эти подходы к созданию объекта отличаются только синтаксисом`

Comment: @DaniilLoban, и это опять не относится к тому, что спрашивалось в вопросе. По ссылке речь только про _литералы **объектов**_. И даже тут могут быть вариации в зависимости от конкретной реализации. По ссылке Grundy не писал ответ, просто исправил опечатку.

Comment: @Grundy обнародуйте наконец-то **свою** точку зрения на данный вопрос

Comment: @DaniilLoban, очевидно, _зависит от реализации_ ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy соглашусь